# Does Exp share spread EVs earned even if the pokemon in battle has maxed EVs?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Will my pokemon in party still gain EVs even if the pokemon in battle has already maxed out its EVs? I'm using Kangaskhan on horde battles with Aegislash on my party. However I already maxed out the EVs of Kangaskhan; will aegislash still receive EVs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every other Pokémon will earn EVs. Similarly, when battling with a level 100 Pokémon, every other Pokémon will earn its own share of experience, even though the Pokémon that battled didn't earn any more.